# Python tkinter canvas shows different shapes in different os?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, operating-system, tkinter-canvas

I am working with python tkinter interface. I found a series of code to dispalay a shape of dragon in canvas window(using arcs and lines).When i run the code in ubuntu os, i got the output as [image]

But, by running the same code in windows os, i got the output as [image].

I couldnt figure out how this problem occurs. And how can i solve this?
(i cant post the code because of large size).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for different OS Tkinter may differ, for example in Mac buttons are rounded, thing that is impossible in windows if you don't use an image, so it has no solution Tkinter it works like this.